# pandas calculate duration between datetime but not considering specific time range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

For clarity here is MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id":[1,2,3,4],
   "start_time":["2020-06-01 01:00:00", "2020-06-01 01:00:00", "2020-06-01 19:00:00", "2020-06-02 04:00:00"], 
   "end_time":["2020-06-01 14:00:00", "2020-06-01 18:00:00", "2020-06-02 10:00:00", "2020-06-02 16:00:00"]
    })
df["start_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_time"])
df["end_time"]   = pd.to_datetime(df["end_time"])
df["sub_time"] = df["end_time"] - df["start_time"]
```

this outputs:

```
    id    start_time               end_time              sub_time
0   1   2020-06-01 01:00:00   2020-06-01 14:00:00        13:00:00
1   2   2020-06-01 01:00:00   2020-06-01 18:00:00        17:00:00
2   3   2020-06-01 19:00:00   2020-06-02 10:00:00        15:00:00
3   4   2020-06-02 04:00:00   2020-06-02 16:00:00        12:00:00
```

but when start_time ~ end_time consists of times range 00:00:00~03:59:59am I want to ignore it(not calculated in sub_time)

So instead of output above I would get:

```
    id    start_time               end_time              sub_time
0   1   2020-06-01 01:00:00   2020-06-01 14:00:00        10:00:00
1   2   2020-06-01 01:00:00   2020-06-01 18:00:00        14:00:00
2   3   2020-06-01 19:00:00   2020-06-02 10:00:00        11:00:00
3   4   2020-06-02 04:00:00   2020-06-02 16:00:00        12:00:00
```

row 0: starting at 01:00:00 do not count until 04:00:00. then 04:00:00 ~ 14:00:00 is 10 hour period

row 2: consider duration from 19:00:00 ~ 24:00:00 and 04:00:00 ~ 10:00:00 thus we get 11:00:00 in sub_time column.

Any suggestions?